# android : customized action when home logo in action bar si clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i changed the logo to an action icon and i want to perform an action when the logo is clicked.

How can i customize the action when the home logo in action bar is clicked?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onOptionsItemSelected()` of your activity, watch for an ID of `android.R.id.home` -- that will be when the home icon/logo is pressed. You can then perform whatever action makes sense (e.g., move to your app's main screen).